# Are there a standard expression serialization format?

Tags: serialization, expression-trees, arithmetic-expressions

I want to write program to serialize/deserialize math formula

Then I was thinking that there could be some JSON format that would already has library in C# and other language so it would be reusable in many platform

Are there any consensus to lay a format like that?

Comment: Err, infix notation? Polish notation? Reverse Polish? No library required.

Comment: @EJP well, I think I need library because it not only +-*/. But also math function like power, sine, logarithm, etc

Comment: @EJP And especially infix notation, it would need library to parse string back into usable function

Comment: So use postfix. Very trivial to parse, and easily extensible to handle whatever math functions you need.